# Cuttlefish doesn't display device screen in WebRTC on AArch64

Tags: android, ubuntu, opengl, android-virtual-device, arm64

This deficiency has been reported by multiple authors on the internet (see https://medium.com/@BushMinusZero/cuttlefish-on-arm64-in-aws-b1f60d937614 and https://junsun.net/wordpress/tag/cuttlefish/ ), and I'm hitting the same problem for myself.

To reproduce:

1. Create an a1.metal instance on AWS, or use any other AArch64 machine that is bare-metal or allows nested virtualization
2. Install Ubuntu 22.04 ARM64
3. Setup ubuntu-desktop on the machine and a VNC server for viewing the screen remotely
4. Setup Firefox on the AArch64 machine
5. Follow the official instructions to setup Cuttlefish: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/cuttlefish-use
6. After launching Cuttlefish according to the official instructions and going to https://localhost:8443 , you can see that no connection to the Android Virtual Device display is established.

I'm attaching the Cuttlefish logs for reference:

Screen output:

```
~/work/avd$ HOME=$PWD ./bin/launch_cvd --daemon --start_webrtc=true
===================================================================
NOTICE:

By using this Android Virtual Device, you agree to
Google Terms of Service (https://policies.google.com/terms).
The Google Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy)
describes how Google handles information generated as you use
Google Services.
===================================================================

launch_cvd I 03-27 08:03:20  2881  2881 main.cc:312] Host changed from last run: 0
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:20  3103  3103 fetcher_config.cpp:220] Could not find file ending in kernel
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:20  3103  3103 fetcher_config.cpp:220] Could not find file ending in initramfs.img
assemble_cvd I 03-27 08:03:20  3103  3103 config_flag.cpp:153] Launching CVD using --config='phone'.
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:20  3103  3103 subprocess.cpp:333] Started (pid: 3106): /home/ubuntu/work/avd/bin/extract-ikconfig
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:20  3103  3103 subprocess.cpp:335] /home/ubuntu/work/avd/boot.img
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:21  3103  3103 subprocess.cpp:333] Started (pid: 3114): /home/ubuntu/work/avd/bin/unpack_bootimg
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:21  3103  3103 subprocess.cpp:335] --boot_img
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:21  3103  3103 subprocess.cpp:335] /home/ubuntu/work/avd/boot.img
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:21  3103  3103 subprocess.cpp:335] --out
assemble_cvd D 03-27 08:03:21  3103  3103 subprocess.cpp:335] /tmp/RXHefo
Failed to load library: libEGL.so
Failed to load library: libEGL.so
Failed to wait for subprocess: subprocess terminated by signal 11.
Failed to wait for subprocess: subprocess terminated by signal 11.
GPU auto mode: did not detect prerequisites for accelerated rendering support, enabling --gpu_mode=guest_swiftshader.
The following files contain useful debugging information:
  Logcat output: /home/ubuntu/work/avd/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/logs/logcat
  Kernel log: /home/ubuntu/work/avd/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/kernel.log
  Point your browser to https://localhost:8443 to interact with the device.
  Launcher log: /home/ubuntu/work/avd/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/logs/launcher.log
  Instance configuration: /home/ubuntu/work/avd/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/cuttlefish_config.json
Virtual device booted successfully
VIRTUAL_DEVICE_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Logs: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JAPyCzKq3PNnenXXrVqUZ7pNKDoxFDUu?usp=sharing

I thought the error is connected with this output `Failed to load library: libEGL.so`, so I tried fixing it by downloading the artifacts from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/common/+/emu-master-dev/swiftshader/linux-aarch64/lib and putting them into `avd/bin` directory. I found with `HOME=$PWD strace -f -v -s150 ./bin/launch_cvd --daemon --start_webrtc=true 2>&1 | fgrep libEGL.so` that Cuttlefish looks for the artifacts exactly there, rather than the system directories.

I also built Messa `llvmpipe`-based software renderer from sources and installed it on the host system. The `libEGL.so` error doesn't get resolved in either of the above ways.

Please, suggest what else I can try.

Comment: Cuttlefish, the development process, has not been tested with Firefox or any other browser, and it is strongly recommended that you should use Google Chrome for its webRTC. The log looks okay to me.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it to work by installing and using Chromium to open https://localhost:8443. It wasn't working on Firefox.